Modelling methodologies to build a single credit cycle covariate to be used in an MSM Model
I am currently looking at building a Multi-State Markov model to do PD estimation as per IFRS9. I am trying to figure out how to incorporate the macro-economic covariate to this model as a single factor. Any suggestions on different modelling methodologies.
There are approaches like OLS regressions as such but my time series being non-stationary it is not giving robust results. Also would be looking for suggestions as to what to model the y variable as against the macro-economic variables while building this model.
